# Should I worry about 'WARNING: Package contains reference to $srcdir'?

Tags: arch-linux, compiling, aur, pkgbuild, makepkg

I was building `font-manager` package from AUR on my Arch system. It is throwing a warning while the process :

```
==> WARNING: Package contains reference to $srcdir 
usr/lib/font-manager/libfontmanager.so.0.7.9
```

Should I worry about this warning ? Is it harmful to my system anyway ?

Comment: The warning is explained on the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Makepkg#WARNING:_Package_contains_reference_to_$srcdir). It was never a problem for me, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen that warning on several packages that I have built in Arch. I always ignore it and haven't suffered any negative consequences yet.

Comment: Do you always check that the software still works if the build directory no longer exists? If not, you may end up with a situation where it works on your machine but not anyone else's.